# Marshall/Unmarshalling Scala Case class with Jackson Jsonformat not working

Tags: scala, jackson-databind

gradle configurations

```
            'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.5',
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12:2.9.5",
            'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.9.5',
```

case class looks like this

```
case class SampleCaseClass(@JsonProperty("a") @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") a: DateTime,
                                    @JsonProperty("b_id") b: String,
                                    @JsonProperty("c_id") c: String) {

}
```

instantiation

```
  val sampleCaseClass =
            SampleCaseClass(
                new DateTime(10L),
                "abc",
                "efg",
            )
```

converting case class to json

```
      val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
      mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
      mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
      mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
      val inputJson = new StringReader(mapper.writeValueAsString(sampleCaseClass))
```

Date value is coming

```
{"year":1970,"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":4,"dayOfYear":1,"era":1,"millisOfDay":3600010,"weekOfWeekyear":1,"weekyear":1970,"monthOfYear":1,"yearOfEra":1970,"yearOfCentury":70,"centuryOfEra":19,"millisOfSecond":10,"secondOfMinute":0,"secondOfDay":3600,"minuteOfHour":0,"minuteOfDay":60,"hourOfDay":1,"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":true,"id":"Europe/Berlin"},"id":"Europe/Berlin"}},"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":true,"id":"Europe/Berlin"},"id":"Europe/Berlin"},"millis":10,"beforeNow":true,"afterNow":false,"equalNow":false}
```

JsonFormat for some reasons not working. where as JsonProperty works

how to make sure that date is properly formatted. I want to do this at case class level, because while converting json back to object I don't want to face any issues. Am trying to insert values into Elasticsearch. I am using springboot 2.7.6, internally it uses 7.17 Elasticsearch version. I am trying to use new JAVA API client to insert the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the issue [How to resolve case class Option[LocalDate] ? #332](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/332) could help to solve your problem. Looks like you need to register the `JavaTimeModule` for the `ObjectMapper`

```scala
new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule).registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
```

also you need to add [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) as dependency. This one has support for **JSR-310 specification** (Java 8 date/time types).

If I'm not wrong, based on the dependencies you listed, you are using `joda time`. In thath case you would need to register the `JodaModule` for the `ObjectMapper` that comes from [jackson-datatype-joda](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda), the dependency that is already imported